# convolutional network with very different input and output dimensions

Tags: keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

If the input to my CNN has 3D images of size [NxNxN], and the output of my CNN has 2D images of size [NxN], what would be a good way to structure the network (in Keras)?  One could think of this as each input being a set of N 2D images of size [NxN], and the output being a single [NxN] image.

One could propagate the input image size through the network, and have the output image be the same size as the input image, but train most of the output image to be 0, and only utilize one [NxN] slice of the output. But this seems computationally expensive to me. What I'm saying is, the network could be composed of Keras Conv3D layers, with padding='same' for each. Then, the output dimension will be [NxNxN], but, effectively, only [1xNxN] would be used on the output.

I guess what I'd like to do is shrink one dimension of the data as it goes through the network, and keep the other 2 dimensions the same. This way you'd have fewer weights to adjust and the learning would go faster compared to keeping all the dimensions the same through the network. As an example, if the network input was [50x50x50], and you could have padding='same' on 2 dimensions, and padding='valid' on the other one dimension, then you could shrink the image in one dimension as it passes through the network. Say you were using a kernel of size 7x7x7. Then after going through a single hypothetical Conv3D layer, the image would be [47x50x50]. After 10 such layers, the image size would be [20x50x50]. And so on.

Is something like this doable? Any other thoughts on how to do this? I wouldn't want to use padding='valid" in all dimensions because then you would lose the spacial context of the pixels.

Thanks in advance. I hope this is clear.